# Breaking text to right top in a div

Tags: html, css, text

i'm trying to make my text in my div go to the top again and start at the top descending to the bottom when it reaches the bottom of my div.

Example:

[image]

My current html is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <ul class="ulstyle">
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
            <li>Text </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this with Html, Css or even Javascript?

Comment: Use CSS `column-count` (webkit compatible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property on parent div

```css
 -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this there are three options.

1. Make two divs side by side
2. Give them `float: left`, this will not put the bottom part to the top though. There will be columns depending on how wide your top div is.
3. Use multi column layout which is not supported in Internet Explorer, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

```
<div id="test">
    <ul class="ulstyle">
        <li>Text 1</li>
        <li>Text 2</li>
        <li>Text 3</li>
        <li>Text 4</li>
        <li>Text 5</li>
        <li>Text 6</li>
        <li>Text 7</li>
        <li>Text 8</li>
        <li>Text 9</li>
        <li>Text 10</li>
        <li>Text 11</li>
        <li>Text 12</li>
        <li>Text 13</li>
        <li>Text 14</li>
        <li>Text 15</li>
    </ul>
</div>

#test {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#test ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.ulstyle {
    -moz-column-count: 6;
    -webkit-column-count: 6;
    column-count: 6;
    moz-column-width: 150px;
    -webkit-column-width: 150px;
    column-width: 150px;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/btabdelkrim/8Laph9sz/1/